# TSQL VARCHAR compression

Tags: t-sql, compression

Is there a huffman or zip compression dll written for TSQL?  I have searched and can't seem to find it.  I want to store compressed data in one field and use a calculated field to display the uncompressed data.

Comment: You may be able to do this in CLR but I'm not sure why you would.  If it's compressed data it may have to be stored as `varbinary`

Comment: Trying to shrink a 100gb table.  The largest field is a text field, and we never search it.  I am seeing also that the table properties tab claims there are 1.6b rows but COUNT(*) returns only 150m rows.  So the table might only be 10gb.  However, we want to 5x increase the data input per day so I still want compression after I get to the bottom of the row count issue.

Comment: In that case you can look at using table or row level compression in SQL Server depending on your version, or you could move that column to another table and set up a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: I looked at table or row level compression and they pretty much say they don't compress varchar fields.  I could see putting the text in a text field which gets stored in another table basically.  This would speed up our searches on the table since the data we search on would be much more local and smaller.  It would be nice to compress the text though.

Comment: Need to first figure out the difference in count.  I have a table that is nothing but a int PK and big text.  Count(*) and properties tab both return 1391712.  If you index the other fields you also get data that is more local and smaller.  If you don't want to index all other search fields then even a 2:1 compression is not going to help much.   Be safe and put the text separate table.  Even if you compress it I would put it in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function in TSQL but you can write your own dll written by C# or VB.net called SQLCLR and add it to your sql.
Now you can use this function.